# Upgrading systems from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: c#, com, x86, 64-bit

I'm a student programmer for my university and I have been tasked with updating our 32 bit lab service programs to 64 bit and have hit a wall. Most of the code converted with no issues except for one library that is the core to most of the package. Whenever I attempt to convert it to 64 bit i get this error:

"P:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1988,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Interop.SensEvents", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project."

Now, I know that this means that there's a mismatch through the architecture and I've tracked the problem down to the reference "interop.sensEvents" being stuck in x86. I can't force it into x64 because it uses COM which I've found online to be a x86 type only unless you do some registry workarounds (which I don't have access to).

My question is: Is there any other way around this that anyone knows of? Maybe an alternative to SENS (unlikely I know) or a way to convert programs to 64 bit if they're using COM? If more detail is needed, I'm happy to comply. We're using windows 10 machines, the code is in c# and the platform is visual studio 2017.

Thank you

Comment: The Interop is usually to work with Microsoft Office Products.  Each version of Office has a different Interop Library.  So downloading the Inerop Library for version of Office that is installed may solve issue.

Comment: You get a 64-bit version of the library or you setup a shim process to host the 32-bit library outside of the main 64-bit process.